# Problem with understanding.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an example in the book of "Abstract algebra by Dummit & Foote " . I didn't understand the indicate part of this proof. Please anyone help.[image]

How did they get class equation from that ?

Comment: The proof uses an unnecessary layer of contradiction. It proves "$G$ non-abelian $\implies p\mid q-1$", but phrases its conclusion as "$G$ non-abelian and $p\nmid q-1\implies$ contradiction". It's not egregious in this case, but injecting unnecessary contradictions is a proof-writing habit that occasionally hampers readability, and makes the theorem less direct, without any actual gain. At least that's my two cents.

Comment: @Arthur is there any another standard proof , you know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an element $g\in G$ has order $p$, then it generates a cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ of order $p$. The centraliser $C(g)$ of $g$ contains this subgroup, but isn't all of $G$, since $g\notin Z(G)$. By Lagrange's theorem, $C(g)=\langle g\rangle$ is the only option left.

The class equation for $G$ reads
$$
|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum [G:C(g)]
$$
where the sum goes over a certain collection of non-central elements $g\in G$. It doesn't really matter how many of them there are, but let's say there are $k$ terms in the sum.

We know $|G|=pq, |Z(G)|=1$, and for any relevant $g$ we have $[G:C(g)]=\frac{|G|}{|\langle g\rangle|}=q$. Inserting this into the above class equation gives the equality you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks, for that.